# deep copy of a generic list

Tags: java, list, deep-copy

I want to make a deep copy of a generic list in Java. How could I improve this code?

```
public interface Deep{}
public class Class1() implements Deep{
    public Class1(Class1 o){
        //implementation of deep copy
    }
}   

public class Class2() implements Deep{
    public Class2(Class2 o){
        //implementation of deep copy
    }
}
```

Implementing deepCopy of List in another class:

```
public List<Deep> deepCopy(List<Deep> inList){
    if(inList.get(0) instanceof Class1){
        List<Deep> newList=new ArrayList<Class1>();
            for (Deep deep : inList) 
            newList.add(new Class1((Class1) deep));
            }
    else if(inList.get(0) instanceof Class2){
        List<Deep> newList=new ArrayList<Class2>();
            for (Deep deep : inList) 
            newList.add(new Class2((Class2) deep));
                  }
}
```

And here is the call:

```
List<Class1> list= new List<Class1>();
//fill list...
List<Class1> aCopy=(List<Class1>) deepCopy(list);
```

Comment: You can probably improve it by not trying to do it.  If you absolutely must do a deep copy, implement it from scratch at the call site; trying to do it generically isn't feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of providing your own interface Deep for this, you could use java library's Cloneable.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html

Most of the java classes already implement this interface.Like ArrayList etc.

Comment: I would suggest looking at [Cloning with generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803971/cloning-with-generics), one of the thing they bring up is how `Cloneable` is a broken interface.